When extending ggplot2, how should I apply scaling functions per group instead of as a whole?
I'm working on a new geom for ggplot2 that allows the user to alter the tint and shade of the colors by mapping it to an aesthetic. (If someone knows of a place this has already been implemented, please save me the headache!) I've got the basics of the geom figured out but I'm not sure that I'm applying the scales correctly because I'm having to rescale the data within draw_panel to use the colour groups instead of it happening automatically.
library(ggplot2)
library(rlang)
library(colorspace)
library(grid)
source("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/7fb4c382/R/utilities-grid.R")

geom_point_tintshade <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL,
                                 stat = "identity", position = "identity",
                                 ..., na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA,
                                 inherit.aes = TRUE) {
  layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomPointTintshade,
        position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
        params = list2(na.rm = na.rm, ...))
}
GeomPointTintshade <- ggproto("GeomPointTintshade", GeomPoint,
                              required_aes = c("x", "y"),
                              non_missing_aes = c("size", "shape", "colour", "tintshade"),
                              default_aes = aes(
                                shape = 19, colour = "black", size = 1.5, fill = NA,
                                alpha = NA, tintshade=0.5
                              ),
                              setup_data = function(data, params){
                                assign("data", data, envir = .GlobalEnv)
                                data$tintshade_group <- data$colour
                                data
                              },
                              draw_panel = function(self, data, panel_params, coord, na.rm = FALSE) {
                                coords <- coord$transform(data, panel_params)
                      # I feel like I shouldn't have to rescale tintshade here...
                                full_range <- range(coords$tintshade)
                                coords_rescaled <- tapply(
                                  X = coords$tintshade, INDEX = coords$tintshade_group,
                                  FUN = function(x) scales::rescale(rank(x), full_range)
                                  )
                                coords$tintshade <- unsplit(coords_rescaled, coords$tintshade_group)
                      # but if I don't then the rescaling isn't applied by group,
                      # instead once as a whole
                                coords$colour <- lighten(coords$colour, amount = (coords$tintshade*2)-1)
                                ggname("geom_point_tintshade",
                                       pointsGrob(
                                         coords$x, coords$y,
                                         pch = coords$shape,
                                         gp = gg_par(
                                           col = alpha(coords$colour, coords$alpha),
                                           fill = fill_alpha(coords$fill, coords$alpha),
                                           pointsize = coords$size
                                         )
                                       )
                                )
                              },
                              draw_key = function(self, ...) draw_key_point(...)
)
scale_tintshade_discrete <- function(name = waiver(), ..., range = c(0.2, 0.8)) {
  discrete_scale(
    aesthetics="tintshade", name = name, ...,
    palette = function(n) seq(range[1], range[2], length.out = n)
  )
}

metab_data <- data.frame(
  metab=rep(c("Alanine", "Threonine", "Glycine", "GBT", "Proline betaine",
              "Carnitine", "DMSP", "DMS-Ac", "Isethionate"), 3),
  metab_group=rep(rep(c("Amino acid", "Betaine", "Sulfur"), each=3), 3),
  tripl=rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each=9),
  area=runif(27)
)
ggplot(metab_data) +
  aes(x = tripl, y = area, color = metab_group, tintshade = metab) +
  geom_point_tintshade(size=4)


Ideally I'd like to skip the setup_data and where I add the tintshade_group column and instead have the non-positional scale training perform this for me (since tintshade_group is just the colour column renamed to avoid scaling) instead of needing to recalculate it within draw_panel but I can't figure out how to tell ggplot that there are groups to scale within instead of just mapping the values as a whole.
Right now the data in coords (pre-recalculation) looks like:
   colour tintshade      x         y PANEL group tintshade_group shape size fill alpha
1 #F8766D     0.200 0.1875 0.5387449     1     1      Amino acid    19    4   NA    NA
2 #F8766D     0.800 0.1875 0.6519035     1     3      Amino acid    19    4   NA    NA
3 #F8766D     0.575 0.1875 0.9545455     1     2      Amino acid    19    4   NA    NA
4 #00BA38     0.500 0.1875 0.6811014     1     5         Betaine    19    4   NA    NA
5 #00BA38     0.725 0.1875 0.2865486     1     6         Betaine    19    4   NA    NA
6 #00BA38     0.275 0.1875 0.3901051     1     4         Betaine    19    4   NA    NA

and I would instead like to have the initial output of coords be (note the different values in the "tintshade" column)
   colour tintshade      x         y PANEL group tintshade_group shape size fill alpha
1 #F8766D     0.200 0.1875 0.5387449     1     1      Amino acid    19    4   NA    NA
2 #F8766D     0.800 0.1875 0.6519035     1     3      Amino acid    19    4   NA    NA
3 #F8766D     0.500 0.1875 0.9545455     1     2      Amino acid    19    4   NA    NA
4 #00BA38     0.500 0.1875 0.6811014     1     5         Betaine    19    4   NA    NA
5 #00BA38     0.800 0.1875 0.2865486     1     6         Betaine    19    4   NA    NA
6 #00BA38     0.200 0.1875 0.3901051     1     4         Betaine    19    4   NA    NA

Is this possible to do with existing functions? Or am I actually doing this the correct way? Part of the motivation for this is that I'm running into downstream problems when trying to construct a legend where it's more difficult to recalculate these values (but that may be a later question...)

I thought there was a scale=“free” option in the faceting functions???

@IRTFM My impression of the scale="free" option is that it means that new scales are calculated independently for each facet, not for each group within it. Here I'm only working with a single facet (via facetNull) so I'm not sure how to implement that in the code as a default for my geom/scale but I'm open to hearing ideas!

I had a hard time understanding your request and thought you were encoding the scale via position.

It seems to me that you are trying to get this aesthetic mapping to work differently from other non-positional aesthetic mappings. For example, if you wanted to do this with a discrete alpha scale, it would be up to the user to specify the values directly using a manual scale. I would strongly advise against writing a ggplot extension that breaks the design principle of using one variable per aesthetic and one aesthetic per scale. Currently your geom is trying to do the job that a scale object should do, and this will cause difficulties for you and surprises for your users.

Also, from a data visualization perspective, the idea of using tint and shade as two dimensions of group membership sets some pretty optimistic expectations on your audience's perceptual abilities and patience. The example plot could show the same information far more clearly and attractively with facets or heat maps. I think the idea of having separate aesthetics for hue, saturation and lightness might be cool or useful for some applications using continuous scales, but for arbitrary mapping to group membership it seems a bit of a flawed concept.

It seems to me that you wish to use 2 dimensions to specify color, essentially mapping one variable to hue and one variable to lightness while holding saturation at a maximum. The problem you are facing is that you want the shade aesthetic to be scaled per group, but at the moment it is scaled across all groups.
The major difficulty here is that you are trying to use an aesthetic mapping in a non-standard way. The ethos of ggplot is that one variable gets mapped to a single aesthetic, and that aesthetic is converted into graphical parameters with a dedicated scaling function that does not take any other variable into account.
Normally, if a user wants to nest aesthetics in the way you describe, the onus is on them to calculate the nesting themself. For example, to do what you are describing with the alpha aesthetic in ggplot, we would need to do something like:
library(ggplot2)

legend_title <- paste0("metabolite group\n\n",
                       "Amino Acid        Betaine              Sulfur   ")

ggplot(within(metab_data, metab <- factor(metab, unique(metab)))) +
  aes(x = tripl, y = area, color = metab, alpha = metab) +
  geom_point(size = 4) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = setNames(rep(c(0.75, 0.5, 0.25), 3), 
                                       unique(metab_data$metab)),
                     guide = guide_legend(ncol = 3, title = legend_title)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = setNames(rep(scales::hue_pal()(3), each = 3), 
                                       unique(metab_data$metab)),
                     guide = guide_legend(ncol = 3, title = legend_title)) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", 
        legend.box = "vertical",
        legend.title.position = "top",
        legend.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))


This is of course a bit too complex to expect your users to do for themselves each time they want to use your shade aesthetic if the intended use is to nest shade within color hue. One reason that this has not already been implemented in the ggplot2 ecosystem is that it is a bit niche; using two non-position aesthetics to indicate nested group membership is normally a very poor choice in data visualization. Color intensity can be difficult to see clearly and requires frequent reference to the legend, making it very difficult for the audience to understand what is going on. In fact, the function scale_alpha_discrete always emits a warning against using it at all for this very reason.
Simplicity is often the key to presenting multi-dimensional data like this, for example using facets one can quickly pick out group membership and area of each observation without any legend.
ggplot(metab_data, aes(metab, area)) + 
  geom_point(color = "gray30", size = 4) + 
  facet_wrap(~ metab_group + tripl, scales = "free_x") + 
  scale_size_area(max_size = 10, breaks = 0:4/4, limits = 0:1) +
  theme_bw(16) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")


If you cannot be persuaded against the idea, then you can define a simple manual shade scale:
scale_shade_manual <- function(..., values, breaks = waiver(), na.value = NA) {
  ggplot2:::manual_scale("shade", values, breaks, ..., na.value = na.value)
}

And a geom that processes the scaled shade aesthetic, remembering to include a draw_key function to produce the appropriate legend:
GeomPointShade <- ggplot2::ggproto("GeomPointShade", GeomPoint,
                                   
  default_aes = aes(shape = 19, colour = "black", size = 1.5, fill = NA, 
                 alpha = NA, stroke = 0.5),
  
  required_aes = c('x', 'y', 'shade'),
  
  draw_panel = function (self, data, panel_params, coord, na.rm = FALSE) {

    if (is.character(data$shape)) {
      data$shape <- ggplot2:::translate_shape_string(data$shape)
    }
    coords <- coord$transform(data, panel_params)
    stroke_size <- coords$stroke
    stroke_size[is.na(stroke_size)] <- 0
    colour_matrix <- plotwidgets::col2hsl(coords$colour)
    colour_matrix[3,] <- coords$shade
    coords$colour <- plotwidgets::hsl2col(colour_matrix)
    
    ggplot2:::ggname("geom_point_shade", 
      grid::pointsGrob(coords$x, coords$y, pch = coords$shape, 
      gp = grid::gpar(col = alpha(coords$colour, coords$alpha), 
                      fill = fill_alpha(coords$fill, 
      coords$alpha), fontsize = coords$size * .pt + stroke_size * 
      .stroke/2, lwd = coords$stroke * .stroke/2)))
  },
  
  draw_key = function (data, params, size) {
    
    if(is.null(data$shade)) data$shade <- 0.5
    if (is.null(data$shape)) {
      data$shape <- 19
    }
    else if (is.character(data$shape)) {
      data$shape <- ggplot2::translate_shape_string(data$shape)
    }
    stroke_size <- data$stroke %||% 0.5
    stroke_size[is.na(stroke_size)] <- 0
    colour_matrix <- plotwidgets::col2hsl(data$colour)
    colour_matrix[3,] <- data$shade
    data$colour <- plotwidgets::hsl2col(colour_matrix)
    grid::pointsGrob(0.5, 0.5, pch = data$shape, 
        gp = grid::gpar(col = alpha(data$colour %||% "black", data$alpha), 
                        fill = fill_alpha(data$fill %||%  "black", data$alpha), 
                        fontsize = (data$size %||% 1.5) * 
                                                .pt + stroke_size * .stroke/2, 
                        lwd = stroke_size * .stroke/2))
  }
)

Now our actual geom_point_shade function could be:
geom_point_shade <- function (mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "identity", 
          position = "identity", ..., na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = TRUE, 
          inherit.aes = TRUE) 
{
  layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomPointShade, 
        position = position, show.legend = show.legend, 
        inherit.aes = inherit.aes, 
        params = rlang::list2(na.rm = na.rm, ...))
}

This allows us to run the same plot code as we did for the alpha aesthetic, except using shade
ggplot(within(metab_data, metab <- factor(metab, unique(metab)))) +
  aes(x = tripl, y = area, color = metab, shade = metab) +
  geom_point_shade(size = 4) +
  scale_shade_manual(values = setNames(rep(c(0.75, 0.5, 0.25), 3), 
                                       unique(metab_data$metab)),
                     guide = guide_legend(ncol = 3, title = legend_title)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = setNames(rep(scales::hue_pal()(3), each = 3), 
                                       unique(metab_data$metab)),
                     guide = guide_legend(ncol = 3, title = legend_title)) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", 
        legend.box = "vertical",
        legend.title.position = "top",
        legend.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))


As I understand it, this is your desired output, but not your desired interface. Your two options here are a wrapper function that takes care of the details, or changing the scaling function so that it accepts a second variable for nesting. This is not a standard thing to do in ggplot, and may cause some confusion in your users. If you are interested, I can demonstrate how it could be done as an addendum to this answer.

Addendum
Whilst it is possible to create a scale object that takes care of the scaling for you, it is complex, and it would also need its own guide, which would have to store information about the nesting variable.
I was able to cobble something together that achieved that result, but as it required a new Geom, a new Scale and a new Guide as well as their boilerplate calling functions, it ran to several hundred lines of code and is therefore not suited to an SO answer. It would also require a lot of development to get it up to production standard. I suspect you were hoping for something simpler.
One way of achieving what you want is to just use a manual scale, but have it wrapped in a function that can access the plot data. This would allow a very natural looking interface:
ggplot(metab_data) +
  aes(x = tripl, y = area, color = metab_group, shade = metab) +
  geom_point_shade(size = 4) +
  scale_shade_nested(nest_within = "colour")


You could implement this as follows:
scale_shade_nested <- function (name = waiver(), nest_within = "group", 
                                min = 0.2, max = 0.8, na.value = 0.5, 
                                breaks = waiver(), labels = waiver()) {

  if(length(nest_within) != 1) stop("Must nest within a single variable")
  
  nest_within <- sub("color", "colour", nest_within, fixed = TRUE)
  pal_func <- function(n) {
    if(n == 1) 0.5 else seq(min, max, length = n)
  }

  structure(list(nest_within = nest_within, palette = pal_func,
            aesthetics = "shade", name = name, breaks = breaks,
            labels = labels), class = 'nested_scale')
}

With a ggplot_add method as follows:
ggplot_add.nested_scale <- function(object, plot, object_name) {
  nest_var <- deparse(rlang::get_expr(p$mapping[[object$nest_within]]))
  nest_var <- plot$data[[nest_var]]
  aes_var <- deparse(rlang::get_expr(p$mapping[[object$aesthetics]]))
  aes_var  <- plot$data[[aes_var]]
  df <- unique(data.frame(aes_var = aes_var, nest_var = nest_var))
  ordering <- seq(nrow(df))
  ordering <- do.call('c', split(ordering, df))
  vals <- do.call('c', lapply(split(df$aes_var, df$nest_var), function(x) {
    object$palette(length(unique(x)))[as.numeric(factor(as.character(x)))]
  }))[order(ordering)]
  
  labs <- if(ggplot2:::is.waive(object$labels)) df$aes_var else object$labels
  plot + ggplot2:::manual_scale(name = object$name, aesthetic = 'shade',
                                values = setNames(vals, labs))
}


Thanks for the thoughts, both in this answer and in your original comments. I’m aware of the potential visualization problems that this could cause but believe it’s still worth implementing given that the current advice scattered across the internet is a hacky version that uses alpha as you illustrate above which is, in my opinion, a greater violation of graphical grammar. Your offer to edit the scaling function to accept a second variable is actually what I’ve been interested in all along and I’m eager to see the addendum you add.

The version with the alpha (and the one with shade) are both pretty poor in data viz terms. I’ll try to look at this tonight to see if I can come up with a method of scaling I could live with.

If it’s any reassurance, I don’t see this applied to point data in actual visualizations but instead to stacked bar plots where the colors are a little larger and the ordering is better structured. Points were just simpler to demonstrate the idea with and I already know how to extend that to rect/poly geoms

@Dubukay see my update. Creating truly nested non-positional scales is possible, but it would require many hours of development to achieve production standard. There is not a simple way to do it within the existing ggplot framework, although my addendum comes close. If you would prefer the ordering of the nested variable to follow the nesting variable in the legend key, you can simply rearrange the vals and labs in the ggplot_add method above.

Hmmmm okay, that's good to know. Appreciate the time and effort you've spent on this one - I'll go ahead and award you the bounty plus my upvote, but I might leave the checkmark off for a bit until I've had the chance to try some additional hacks myself.

Out of curiosity, why'd you use plotwidgets::hsl2col instead of the colorspace::lighten function I had? Any reason to prefer the plotwidgets one?

A much simpler way to accomplish this would be, for example:
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
library(purrr)

df <- tribble(
  ~a, ~b, ~x, ~y,  
   "lawful",      "good", 1, 1,
   "lawful",   "neutral", 1, 2,
   "lawful",      "evil", 1, 3,
  "neutral",      "good", 2, 1,
  "neutral",   "neutral", 2, 2,
  "neutral",      "evil", 2, 3,
  "chaotic",      "good", 3, 1,
  "chaotic",   "neutral", 3, 2,
  "chaotic",     "evil" , 3, 3
) |> 
  mutate(
    a = factor(a, levels = c("lawful", "neutral", "chaotic")),
    b = factor(b, levels = c("good", "neutral", "evil")),
    name = paste(a, b),
    name  = ifelse (name == "neutral neutral", "true neutral", name),
    name = fct_inorder(name)
  )

pal <- expand.grid(
  a = c("lawful", "neutral", "chaotic"),
  b = c("good", "neutral", "evil")) |>
  mutate(
    a = factor(a, levels = c("lawful", "neutral", "chaotic")),
    b = factor(b, levels = c("good", "neutral", "evil")),
    name = paste(a, b),
    name  = ifelse (name == "neutral neutral", "true neutral", name),
    name = fct_inorder(name),
    hue = case_when(
      a == "lawful" ~ "210",
      a == "neutral" ~ "60",
      a == "chaotic" ~ "0"
    ),
    lightness = case_when(
      b == "good" ~ 80,
      b == "neutral" ~ 50,
      b == "evil" ~ 10,
    ),
    chroma = case_when(
      a == "lawful" ~ 100,
      a == "neutral" ~ 0,
      a == "chaotic" ~ 100,
    ),
    hex = hcl(h = hue, l = lightness, c = chroma)
    ) 

values = set_names(pal$hex, pal$name)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = name))+
  geom_point(size = 6)+
  scale_color_manual(
    values = values)+
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom",
  )+
  guides(
    color = guide_legend(
      title = "Alignment",
      nrow = 3,
      byrow = FALSE
  ))

